# Erro ao realizar rota android

Tags: android, google-maps

```
08-24 22:52:53.529 9872-9880/br.com.anjodarua E/AndroidHttpClient: Leak found
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed
                                                                       at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.<init>(AndroidHttpClient.java:156)
                                                                       at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(AndroidHttpClient.java:142)
                                                                       at br.com.anjodarua.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:352)


package br.com.anjodarua;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.anjodarua.Entity.notificacao;
import br.com.anjodarua.Rest.NotificacaoRest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, android.location.LocationListener {
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private AlertDialog alerta;
    public EditText edt_origem;
    public EditText edt_destino;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final String TAG = "V2GPS";
    public static Location retorno;
    List<notificacao> listNotificacao;
    private List<LatLng> list;
    LatLng latLng;
    MarkerOptions options;
    private long distance;
    private Polyline polyline;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        edt_origem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_origem);
        edt_destino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_origem) ;

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
        //Inicia transacao para add fragment no act.
         mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void showFragment(Fragment fragment,String nome){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            showFragment(new MapsFragment(),"MapFragnent");
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public void pegaCoordenada(View view){
        final Location loc = retorno;

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mensagem, null);
        final EditText edt_msg = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_msg);
        Button bnt_confirmar = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.bnt_confirma);
        bnt_confirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String titulo = edt_msg.getText().toString();
                    String result ="";
                    for (int i=0; i<titulo.length(); i++) {
                        char c = titulo.charAt(i);
                        if (c == ' '){
                            result = result + "%20";
                        }else{
                            result = result + c;
                        }
                    }
                    new NotificacaoRest().insereNotificacao(result,loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Coordenadas Gravadas com sucesso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                alerta.dismiss();
                latLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());
                options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.title(edt_msg.getText().toString());
                options.position(latLng);

                mMap.addMarker(options);


            }
        });
        builder.setView(layout);
        alerta = builder.create();
        alerta.show();



    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {

            try {
                listNotificacao = new NotificacaoRest().buscaNotificacaoo();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mMap = googleMap;
            for(int i =0; i < listNotificacao.size(); i++){
                latLng = new LatLng(listNotificacao.get(i).getLatitude(),listNotificacao.get(i).getLongitude());
                options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.title(listNotificacao.get(i).getTitulo());
                options.position(latLng);

                mMap.addMarker(options);
            }
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);


            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Ativa o gps
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        retorno = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(retorno.getLatitude(), retorno.getLongitude());




    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"status foi alterado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Provide abilitado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Provide desabilitado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    //****************************rotas**************************
    public void drawRoute(){
        PolylineOptions po;

        if(polyline == null){
            po = new PolylineOptions();

            for(int i = 0, tam = list.size(); i < tam; i++){
                po.add(list.get(i));
            }

            po.color(Color.BLACK).width(4);
            polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);
        }
        else{
            polyline.setPoints(list);
        }
    }
    /* ***************************************** ROTA ***************************************** */

    public void getRouteByGMAV2(View view) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        EditText etO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_origem);
        EditText etD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_destino);
        String origin = URLEncoder.encode(etO.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
        String destination = URLEncoder.encode(etD.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

        getRoute(new LatLng(-20.195403, -40.234478), new LatLng(-20.304596, -40.291813));
    }





    // WEB CONNECTION
    //public void getRoute(final String origin, final String destination){
    public void getRoute(final LatLng origin, final LatLng destination){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                        /*String url= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                                + origin+"&destination="
                                + destination+"&sensor=false";*/
                String url= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                        + origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude+"&destination="
                        + destination.latitude+","+destination.longitude+"&sensor=false";


                HttpResponse response;
                HttpGet request;
                AndroidHttpClient client = null;
                client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("route",MainActivity.this);

                request = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    response = client.execute(request);
                    final String answer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            try {
                                //Log.i("Script", answer);
                                list = buildJSONRoute(answer);
                                drawRoute();
                            }
                            catch(JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }




    // PARSER JSON
    public List<LatLng> buildJSONRoute(String json) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray routes = result.getJSONArray("routes");

        distance = routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance").getInt("value");

        JSONArray steps = routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
        List<LatLng> lines = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        for(int i=0; i < steps.length(); i++) {
            Log.i("Script", "STEP: LAT: "+steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location").getDouble("lat")+" | LNG: "+steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location").getDouble("lng"));


            String polyline = steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");

            for(LatLng p : decodePolyline(polyline)) {
                lines.add(p);
            }

            Log.i("Script", "STEP: LAT: "+steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("end_location").getDouble("lat")+" | LNG: "+steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("end_location").getDouble("lng"));
        }

        return(lines);
    }




    // DECODE POLYLINE
    private List<LatLng> decodePolyline(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> listPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)), (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            Log.i("Script", "POL: LAT: "+p.latitude+" | LNG: "+p.longitude);
            listPoints.add(p);
        }
        return listPoints;
    }




}
```

o json ele percorre e me retorna o line

Comment: Está dando erro em qual linha meu caro?

Comment: client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("route",MainActivity.this);
 nessa linha ,quando ele retorna o lines do json, ele da erro , e o lines esta certo

Comment: Eu coloquei uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149005/35406) aqui [nesta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148975/erro-ao-realizar-rota-android-androidhttpclient-leak-found).